# Splitting a list of strings into sub lists based on their length

Tags: python, list

If for instance I have a list

```
['My', 'Is', 'Name', 'Hello', 'William']
```

How can I manipulate it such that I can create a new list

```
[['My', 'Is'], ['Name'], ['Hello'], ['William']]
```

Comment: do you have any range of length for each groupings?

Comment: String length is arbitrary, as well as the amount of strings.

Comment: What have you tried so far? BTW, what rules are you applying to get your goal?

Comment: I think I have an idea to do it using dictionary's now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [itertools.**groupby**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ['My', 'Is', 'Name', 'Hello', 'William']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=len)]
[['My', 'Is'], ['Name'], ['Hello'], ['William']]
```

If however the list is not already sorted by length you will need to sort it first as **[@recnac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11263560/recnac)** mentions in the comments below:

```
>>> l2 = ['My', 'Name', 'Hello', 'Is', 'William']
>>> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(l2, key=len), key=len)]
[['My', 'Is'], ['Name'], ['Hello'], ['William']]
```

Comment: It will get wrong, when list is not sorted by len, such as `['My', 'Name', 'Hello', 'Is', 'William']` will output `[['My'], ['Name'], ['Hello'], ['Is'], ['William']]`, you have to sort it first.

Comment: By having to sort first this makes the average time complexity of this solution *O(n log n)* rather than *O(n)*.

Comment: so here is a question, which solution is better, dict or sort & groupby, consider time and space? I have no idea : )

Comment: I have solved my question but have accepted yours since it is the shortest.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a dict that maps word lengths to a list of matching words, and then get the list of the dict's values:

```
l = ['My', 'Is', 'Name', 'Hello', 'William']
d = {}
for w in l:
    d.setdefault(len(w), []).append(w)
print(list(d.values()))
```

This outputs:

```
[['My', 'Is'], ['Name'], ['Hello'], ['William']]
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi guys I have also found a solution, while it is not the most concise I thought it would be worth sharing

```
data = ['My', 'Is', 'Name', 'Hello', 'William']
dict0 = {}
for index in data:
    if len(index) not in dict0:
        dict0[len(index)] = [index]
    elif len(index) in dict0:
        dict0[len(index)] += [index]
list0 = []
for i in dict0:
    list0.append(dict0[i])
print(list0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `dict` to record the string group by length, `defaultdict` is used for convenient here.

```
from collections import defaultdict

str_list = ['My', 'Is', 'Name', 'Hello', 'William']
group_by_len = defaultdict(list)
for s in str_list:
    group_by_len[len(s)].append(s)

result = list(group_by_len.values())
```

output:
`[['My', 'Is'], ['Name'], ['Hello'], ['William']]`

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )